# "ASP.NET web-based applications is my primary focus."

Tags: phrases, grammaticality

Is this grammatically correct? Should I use **is** instead of **are**?

> ASP.NET web-based applications **is** my primary focus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have stated, it would be normal to use *are* to agree with the plural subject *applications*. This is kind of a gray area, however, and arguments could made for either side. If you are taking the idea of "ASP.NET web applications" as a singular pursuit, then you could use *is*. The understanding would be that you are omitting some syntax, such as "Developing in [ASP.NET web app.ications]" ...

That said, in cases where you're unsure how to proceed, it is the simplest thing in the world to simply reverse the order of the sentence:

> My primary focus is ASP.Net web-based applications.

Note that in a resume situation, although @masarah has advised you that "web-based" is a redundancy when talking about ASP.Net, it probably doesn't hurt to be a little redundant to drive home the point about them being web-based. You never know what sort of clueless HR person your resume may need to filter through before reaching someone who can make a decision about your skills, in which case the minor pleonasm is likely to go unnoticed.

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about plural "applications" like in your example, you should use **are**.

Also, off-topic: All ASP.NET applications are web-based, so you do not need to point that out specifically

Answer (score 1):

In that sentence, it is correct to use *are*, not *is*.

I would rephrase the sentence as one of the following sentences.

> ASP.NET is my primary focus.
>   Developing in ASP.NET is my primary focus.
>   Developing applications in ASP.NET is my primary focus.